# Strength of connector attachment to PCB

Tags: pcb, connector, standard

Is there an industry standard or MIL-STD that specifies the force a connector needs to withstand before coming off a PCB?

Comment: There are multiple standards for everything. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. There are so many civilian, military and NASA standards that you need to do some research of your own. What type of connector? What standard is the connector made with? What grade of PCB and how thick? We do not have automated search engines to do this work for us, and this would waste much of our time. We do not do 'shopping' for customers for such broad topics.

Comment: IEC 60512 talks about connector strength.

Comment: A single wire crimp is usually a 5 lb pull test. But I know DC power jacks and headphone jacks after a lot of abuse fail with less force and more repetition.

Comment: "The great thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from" - Maxum Integrated

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This should give you some idea.

**This commercial PCB connector test [site](http://www.mecmesin.com/pcb-component-pull-off-test-cs28) is consistent with the level of force in the table <s>below</s>** above**

Comment: It seems the naysayer has no voice (-1) poor form.